# How to mock URLconnection so that I can change the return value for getLastModified method in java?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

How to mock URLconnection so that I can change the return value for getLastModified method? I've tried a few different approaches like

```
  @Spy
    Watcher watcher;

    @Mock
    URLConnection connection;

    @Test
    void status() throws IOException {
        Mockito.mock(connection.getClass());
        doReturn(connection).when(watcher).create(any());
        doReturn((long) 3).when(connection).getLastModified();

        Watcher watcher = new Watcher();

        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.ats");
        ConcreteObserver obs1 = new ConcreteObserver(watcher, url);
}
```

In watcher class I would have

```
public URLConnection create(URL url) throws IOException {
        URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
        return connect;
    }
```

and also some method to check the LastModifiedDate. However my last modifiedDate always returns the value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe...

```java
    // No need for a spy

    @Test
    void status(
        @Mock final URL urlMock,
        @Mock final URLConnection urlConnectionMock
    ) throws Exception {

        // given: The desired URL-related mocking
        when(urlMock.openConnection)
            .thenReturn(urlConnectionMock);

        when(urlConnectionMock.getLastModified())
            .thenReturn(3L);

        // and:
        final Watcher watcher = new Watcher();

        // and:
        final ConcreteObserver obs1 = new ConcreteObserver(watcher, url);
        

        // when: The action to be tested happens
        ...


        // then: Assert/verify the results
        ...
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: looks good but how do I mock a final class (URL) if I could ask?

Comment: That's a pretty common, straight-forward, question. If you are going to use Mockito, you really should read it's documentation (the answer to this last question is in there). Alternatively, Google "mockito final class".